# Select Clause not working with Content Delivery OData web service

Tags: content-delivery

I am trying to fetch some of the values from content delivery web service but seems 'select'
is not working or I am doing it correctly, please suggest.

> https://:8444/cd_webservice/odata.svc/Pages?oauth_token=client_id%3Dtridion%26AllowedServices%3DcontentService%26Role%3DTridion+test+account%26FirstName%3DSDL%26LastName%3DTridion%26expiresOn%3D1411457494045%26digest%3D0RrpTpZuir4T4%2FhF1YpiHxNZaFlpUfMqKPbhtlM1zos%3D&**$select=ComponentId,ComponentPresentations&$expand=ComponentPresentations**&$filter(ComponentId
>   eq 1442)=

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange. In its current form this question is a bit broad - could you try and add some more detail please? What results are you seeing? What have you tried to do to resolve it? What version of Tridion is this? etc This will enable the community to help you

Answer (score 3):

Last I worked with the CD Webservice (Tridion 2011 SP1), the `select` clause was not an available/supported feature, despite it being part of the OData spec.

For Tridion 2013 SP1, it doesn't look like `select` has it in the Tridion API either (here: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2F41CB23-912F-4149-9C16-34AB00E67E4E).  You can only $expand, $top, and $skip.

Comment: That page does state that the Content Delivery WebService is "a partial implementation of the OData protocol". I've heard it jokingly called "OData 1.5". We're updating to V4 and we'll do the full spec now... but will take a few months